# how to add top border?

Tags: android

**curently done:** menu working fine with selector color change.

**i want:** to add a border on selected menu item. please check image for result i want.

**attched:** 1. activitymain 2. selector 3. menu_nevigation

can i get border on selected item.

**activityMain.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Home"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_navigation"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow"/>
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorcustom"
        app:itemTextColor="@drawable/selector"
        app:itemIconTint="@drawable/selector"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_navigation"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**selector.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:state_selected="true"
        android:color="#333333"
        />
    <item
        android:state_selected="false"
        android:color="#a6a6a6"/>
</selector>
```

**menu_navigation.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:title="Home"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_home"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/about"
        android:title="About"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_about"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:title="Test"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_test"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/term"
        android:title="Term"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_term"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/setting"
        android:title="Setting"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_setting"/>
</menu>
```

[image: Result Image]

Comment: https://material.io/develop/android/components/bottom-navigation/

Comment: but there is no border..... @Pavneet_Singh